# Help with WinAPI wrapper

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, wrapper

I've been making a simple WinAPI wrapper, and I've run into a pretty big problem. Somewhere in the code, the Window class's handle (HWND) is set to NULL, and it's required to process the messages. I've been looking over the code for an hour now, and I can't find anything. Can anyone help?

[Git repository](https://github.com/PiMaster/Easywin)

I'm pretty sure the logic error happens somewhere in Declarations...\Window.hpp and Declarations...\Application.hpp, because those are the only files that hold code that is being called.

Comment: that's too big, you should learn to use debugger. most debuggers have watch capability, use that.

Comment: +1 for deciding to write a GUI toolkit as an exercise for learning C++. That's the spirit! :-)

Comment: Set a data break point (or whatever it is called in your debugger) and arrange that the debugger breaks at the point where NULL is written.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe, I've been programming in C++ for more than two years now... I just REALLY hate programming using the WinAPI, and I had time on my hands, so I started doing this.

Comment: Just curious, why is everyone assuming I'm just learning C++?

Comment: @PiMaster: re "why is everyone assuming [you are] learning C++", that's because everything you say and show shouts loudly that you're learning not just C++ but also programming. it may be a good idea to try to start with some less over-complex language like C# or Java.

Comment: Like I've said, I've been programming in C++ for years now. I also know Python, which you could say is sufficiently "less over-complex," _and_ I'm taking a course in Java. In fact, C++ was my first language, if you don't count GML (I don't). Now tell me, what **exactly** am I saying that "shouts loudly that [I'm] learning not just C++ but also programming?"

Comment: @PiMaster: Let's ignore your programming capabilities, since it is totally irrelevant to this question. Right now you have a link to your code. That's good, you have some kind of code we can look at. However, nobody here on Stack Overflow is paid to look at other people's code. As LeleDumbo said, it's way too much to look at. You need to put up a *self-contained and minimal* code snippet that reproduces the problem. That way, we can come up with an answer faster, and you'll probably even figure out what's wrong with it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with this:

```
namespace WinAPI{
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <commctrl.h>
}
```

Don't do that.

It can be made to work, at the cost of possibly having to update your code for every new SDK release, but it's definitely not something for a beginner.

Here's how to include the `<windows.h>` header in C++:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef STRICT
#define STRICT
#undef NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
```

Place that in a wrapper header.

Include the wrapper in the global namespace.

Oh, the question you *asked* about, the logic error that made your HWND value disappear? You can't really expect others to debug your code.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: That really doesn't help me at all... The library compiles as-is, so I won't worry about it until it actually becomes a problem. Especially considering I can simply replace "WinAPI::" with "" using Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already familiar with `assert()`, this may be a good time to learn about it. An assertion is an expression that you believe is true, and which you'd like the debugger to check. In your case, you could look at all the places which update the `HWND`, and write `assert(newHWNDvalue != NULL);`.

Assertions are a form of comment. Unlike `//`, the compiler compiles them and the debugger does check them, and therefore they don't go stale over time.

`assert` is a macro, and you'll need to include the `<cassert>` header. In release builds, the asserted expression is not compiled, so there's no overhead. That means that you can usually afford non-trivial checks. For complex classes, it may be useful to add a `private: bool CheckInvariants() const` method, so you can `assert(CheckInvariants());` in other members.